# caret position changing according to current mouse position in textarea

Tags: javascript, position, textarea, caret

Is there any way to set caret's position according to current mouse's position in textarea.

When user drag some selected text and moving in the textarea, caret's position will change during to current mouse's position so that user can specify the inserting position conveniently.

I mimic the drag and drop event, but I didn't find an effective way to changing caret's position. Any idea or examples will be helpful.

Comment: I'm guessing you are trying to set the text cursor.  Is that what you mean by caret's position?

Comment: You can use [this](http://blog.vishalon.net/index.php/javascript-getting-and-setting-caret-position-in-textarea/) to set caret's position.

Comment: Thanks @Kirill , but how to get the pos when mouse moving?